# Java: Why wouldn't threads terminate

Tags: java, multithreading

I don't understand why my threads in my simple program always fail to terminate.
I think its a easy problem but i don't see why. I think a simple exec.shutdown(); should close my Threadpool without the try and catch for exec.shutdownNow(); but dam not sure.

class 1:  test ( implements a class that is running a Threadpool )

```
public class test {


 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    ExecServicrunnen x = new ExecServicrunnen();

    x.runningThreads();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    x.getThreadtoStop();
 }
}
```

class 2: ExecServicerunnen ( implements a Threadpool with MyTask() as Runnables )

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class ExecServicrunnen {

private volatile boolean solange = true;


 public void runningThreads(){
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    while(solange){
        exec.execute(new myTask());


    }
    exec.shutdown();
    try{
        if(!exec.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)){
            exec.shutdownNow();
        }
    } catch ( InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        exec.shutdownNow();
            }
 }

 public void getThreadtoStop(){
    solange = false;
 }
}
```

class 3: myTask ( just running waiting for a while )

```
public class myTask implements Runnable{

public void run() {

// doSomething

try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

The program always fails to terminate.

Comment: ah now it does compile, i changed the names of the methods at x for better reading but forgot to change the method names in the object itself.

Comment: The Thread problem is still there though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deadlock.

`x.runningThreads();` does not return before `x.getThreadtoStop();` is called, but `x.getThreadtoStop();` is only called after `x.runningThreads();` returned. Voilà, the threads never can get stopped.

The mistake is that `runningThreads()` is running *synchronously* inside the main thread and not in its own thread. The main thread cannot send to itself the signal to terminate while waiting for the signal to terminate.

Without changing the structure of your code too much, you can solve this with another thread, like:

```
public class ExecServicrunnen implements Runnable {

  private volatile boolean solange = true;

  // Rename runningThreads() to run():
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // The former code of runningThreads() here...
  }

}
```

-

```
public class test {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    ExecServicrunnen x = new ExecServicrunnen();

    // Have ExecServicrunnen run in its own thread:
    new Thread( x ).start();

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    x.getThreadtoStop();

  }

}
```

By the way, that boolean `solange` logic should in most cases be realized via [`Thread.interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) and [`Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) instead.

Comment: how can i avoid this? because whenever i start 2 objects in a thread ( main method ) it will be executed synchronously.

Comment: I could call a return or break inside getThreadtoStop() and put it before runningThreads() where waiting counter or whatever will be initialized inside of ExecServicerunnen but i guess there are better solutions.